# Leaflet map - custom markers from CSV and referring to CSV / GeoJSON marker properties?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, csv, markers

I run a non-profit online resource called the Megalithic Portal and have created a Leaflet map that uses `Leaflet.geoCSV` to load in points from a CSV file
https://github.com/joker-x/Leaflet.geoCSV

To see ultimately what I'm hoping to create, I've made a map with several thousand megalithic sites, based on data from the Megalithic Portal

Here's the full map
http://www.megalithic.co.uk/leaflet_megalith_map-old.html

So far so good but I'm struggling with the JavaScript to get any further

I've created a simpler test map here for debugging purposes:

http://www.megalithic.co.uk/leaflet_megalith_map.html

I can load in the CSV points, and loop around the marker properties as in the code below (`var clave`) which outputs the CSV data in the marker popups.

What I'm struggling with is how do I refer to the properties individually , e.g.

```
popup += 'Colour=' + feature.properties.Colour;
```

(which is wrong as it shows as 'undefined' in the popup)

I think the CSV loads in as an extension of the GeoJSON format
http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

The second thing I'd like to do is to display custom markers set by a column in the CSV.

eg in the properties I have Icon: tp6
 Icon: tg60 etc

I would like to create a different marker for each point based on this property - 
Do I need to do this as part of the `onEachFeature` and loop around all the markers to set the property?

I've tried the following (full code below) but it doesn't work so I must have the syntax wrong:

```
iconUrl: 'images/mapic/' + feature.properties.Icon + '.gif'

var bankias = L.geoCsv(null, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        var popup = 'SID='+ feature.properties['SID'] +'<br />';
        popup += 'Colour='+ feature.properties.Colour +'<br />';
        for (var clave in feature.properties) {
            var title = bankias.getPropertyTitle(clave);
            var csvtext = feature.properties[clave]; 
            //if (title != 'SID' && title != 'Colour' && title != 'Icon' && title != 'CatID' && title != 'TypeID') {
                popup += '<b>'+title+':</b> '+csvtext+'<br />';
            //}
        }
        layer.bindPopup(popup);
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon:L.icon({
                //iconUrl: 'images/mapic/' + feature.properties.Icon + '.gif', // WRONG
                iconUrl: 'leaflet/images/marcador-bankia.png',
                shadowUrl: 'leaflet/images/marker-shadow.png',
                iconSize: [25,41],
                shadowSize:   [41, 41],
                shadowAnchor: [13, 20]
            })
        });
    },
    firstLineTitles: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For geoJson you use mixed case as in my JSFiddle example which worked:

http://jsfiddle.net/megalithic/zuz4urb7/

But the CSV plugin lowers the case of all the variables - but by no means obvious so I thought I should follow up with the working code - CSV users be aware!

Working map
http://www.megalithic.co.uk/leaflet_megalith_map.html

working code

```
var bankias = L.geoCsv(null, {
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
var popup = '';
popup += feature.properties.name +'<br>'+feature.properties.type + '<br>' + feature.properties.colour + '<br>';
if (feature.properties.condition == -1) {popup += 'Condition:Destroyed<br>';}
if (feature.properties.condition > 0) {popup += 'Condition:'+feature.properties.condition +'<br>';}
if (feature.properties.ambience > 0) {popup += 'Ambience:'+feature.properties.ambience +'<br>';}
if (feature.properties.access > 0) {popup += 'Access:'+feature.properties.access +'<br>';}
if (feature.properties.accuracy > 0) {popup += 'Accuracy:'+feature.properties.accuracy +'<br>';}
    popup += '<a target="_blank" href="article.php?sid='+feature.properties.sid+'">Link to site</a>';
    layer.bindPopup(popup);
},
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon:L.icon({
            // modify icon
            iconUrl: 'images/mapic/'+feature.properties.icon+'.gif',
            iconSize: [20,20],
            })
        });
    },
    firstLineTitles: true
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply but that fixed it - appreciated!